# How to check total ink coverage using open source tools?

Tags: print-design, pdf, resource-recommendations, open-source

Any open source tool to check total ink coverage in PDF files (vector artwork) ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you could try with [SK1 Project](https://sk1project.net/)
It's a lot like inkscape but made with printing in mind.